# Giving an order to my numbers natsort(); doesn't work well

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm having problems while I'm loading content from my database.
In my DB I have a table where it holds my gallery images.
In my row called title is set up as text because the values I wanted to use are: hashtag and then a number like this #1 #2 ... and so on.

So I'm loading my content like this...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
$run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
        {  

            echo'....... ';}
```

but the problem is that when I order by title I'm getting these numbers

hastag 90

hastag 9-2

hastag 9-1

So I'm using ORDER BY title DESC why isn't my biggest number (hashtag 706) the first?

[image: here is an picture of it...]

I tried to use `natsort();` but it didn't work because it keeps the same thing.

[image: here is one more pic of my problem but in an other page ...]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9-2` isn't a number. It's a **STRING**, so that means your `title` field is a text type (char, varchar), and STRING sorting rules apply. That means the strings are compared "character-by-character", and not "number-by-number".

```
9-2
7
abc

comparison a) "9" > "7" -> true
comparison b) "-" > "" -> true
comparison c) "2" > "" -> true
```

similarly:

```
9-2
706
abc

comparison a) "9" > "7" -> true   (ascii 57 > ascii 55)
comparison b) "-" > "0" -> false  (ascii 45 > ascii 48)
comparison c) not necessary, 9-2 is already "bigger" than 706
```

So `9-2` is a BIGGER string than `706`, because 9>7 is always true.

Comment: So how can i fix this mess?

Comment: write your own custom sort comparison function, probably. the values aren't something that can be handled by the provided tools.

Comment: thx for this tip bro, i will try to do a custom sort comparison function, im still learning php, i've got  to study now, how im going to do that. if you know where can i read about this share me a link.. Huge thx for you explanation.

Comment: if i create a new row title that have to hold numbers and simbols like... 1, 1-1 , 1-2 which type that  my title shall be?

Comment: string, obviously. `-` is not a valid character in a number, except at the start as the positive/negative sign.

Comment: CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, VARBINARY, BLOB, TEXT, ENUM, and SET are string types  but which one shall i use ?